# PLC Simulator for communication

Tags: c#, tcp, plc, modbus

I want to communicate PLC over MODBUS TCP. 
But I have not a PLC yet. I am waiting for coming it.

I can not find any tool which simulate PLC. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Recommendations isn't really what we do here, but a search for "plc simulator modbus" gives this hit: http://www.plcsimulator.org/